# How to crop scanned image using C#?

Tags: c#, crop, aforge

I have a scanned image of a book page and i need to crop this scan for leaving only page area. I tried to use AForge to detect page borders, but it doesn't work because the space which i need to crop may contain little "light" areas (due to scanner quality) and edge detector detects borders there. That's why this is bad idea as for me.

Could you recommend something?

P.S. Please don't tell me to use non-free libraries.

===========================================================

I've figured it out. Thanks guys for your attention!!!

Comment: Does this have to be an automated process or can a user crop the image?

Comment: Yes, it has to be an automated process because there are 2 or 3 millions of scans.

Comment: Hi @ieaglle, how did you do it?

Comment: Well... I think I have done it, basic algorithm: convert to grayscale, invert (in my case original background is white), use blobcounter to get rectangles (set threshold to your acceptance value), "merge" the resulting rectangles to get the super-set rectangle that contains all the Blobs, use crop... done.

Comment: hello @JoseAraujo, at first mine solution was just like yours, but about 20-30% of images were cropped wrong. So I've decided to use SusanCornerDetector. Results were much better (up to 10 images in 1000 were cropped wrong). The code you can find [here](http://ieaglle.blogspot.com/2012/01/blog-post_8068.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I've figured it out. The code you can find [here](http://ieaglle.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/blog-post_8068.html). Though text is in ukrainian  the code should be understandable. It uses [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net) (I had problems with greyscaling images using standart .Net Framework options, so I'm greyscaling using FreeImage assembly) and [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/).

Comment: 5 years later I need to do exactly the same but the url you're point out is dead. Can you share the code you written to solve the crop? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need the coordinates of the page edges.
There is an open-source project http://outliner.codeplex.com/ that makes vectorization of the edges. But this project is written in C++.

Comment: Nice thing, but i have bad relationships with C++ and porting the code to C# will be a nightmare for me. Anyway thank you for your attention!